# What is the expected behavior of posting a form with an expired auth token in asp.net mvc with openid connect via azure ad?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, authentication, openid-connect

I have an Asp.Net MVC 5 web application that uses OpenId Connect via Azure AD to manage user authentication. I think I understand that once authenticated, the auth token is valid for one hour at which point the OWIN middleware will handle refreshing the auth token in the background without the user having to be redirected to the login page and re-enter their username/password. I have observed this by watching the address change in the address bar of the browser after the auth token expires.

My problem is that I have form that users stay on for a long time (60+ minutes) while they are doing interviews and entering in data. The auth token expires and when the user tries to submit the form the auth token refresh happens in the background and the form is never posted to my application. Instead, the view is refreshed (from the HTTP GET that happens after the auth token is refreshed) and the user loses all of the data they've collected over the last hour.

Is this the expected behavior or do I have something configured incorrectly?